# Missing end comment mark "*/" error on SQL Server 2008, not on 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A script that had run without a problem on SQL Server 2005 now throws an error on SQL Server 2008:

> Missing end comment mark '*/'.

Here's the script

```
/********************************************************************************************************
Script: ED demographic update_new.sql
Author: ADR
Purpose: Uses tbl_patient_history in PHD to update patient demographics at time of attendance. Supersedes
         ED demographic update_old.sql, which relied on the data warehouse.
*********************************************************************************************************/

USE DB1

EXEC pr_printdate 'ED Demographic Update Start'

/*
DROP TABLE temp_ae_demo_update

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_ae_demo_update](
    [aed_attendance_id] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ae_arr_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [patient_id] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [patient_trust_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [birth_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [marital_status] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ethnic_code] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [sex] int NULL,
    [nhs_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [patient_forename] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_surname] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_add_1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_add_2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_add_3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_add_4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [patient_postcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [regd_gp_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [regd_practice_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [gp_postcode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [demo_updated] [int] NOT NULL
)
*/
```

etc etc... this is the only portion of the script containing comments and the error occurs in this section. Errors reported:

> Msg 113, Level 15, State 1, Server UBHNT126, Line 4
>   Missing end comment mark '*/'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server UBHNT126, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near '*'.

There are no `go` statements in the header block - which I'd usually look for in this situation do any other statements other than "GO" cause the same error?

This doesn't happen on 2005, only 2008. I'm not too worried about this specific case, as I can just remove the comment, but we're porting an entire system over to 2008 and I'd like to have a fix in hand for other cases where this could recur.

ALSO - this only occurs when I call the script on the server (from a cmdexec in a job) not if I run the script in ssms (whether 2008 or 2005)

Stored proc create statement :

```
    USE [PHD]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pr_printdate]    Script Date: 04/04/2013 13:24:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO



ALTER procedure [dbo].[pr_printdate] @printext char(30) as
set nocount on
select '**** ' + rtrim(@printext) + ' **** timestamp: ' + convert(char(20), getdate())
set nocount off

GO
```

COmmand to call script:

```
osql /e /n /S SERVER /U xxxxx /P xxxxx /d PHD /i "\\SERVER\phdadmin\SQL\AE Monthly\ED_Demographic_update_new.sql" /o "\\SERVER\PHDAdmin\LOG\ED_Demographic_update_new.log"
```

Comment: The error (some unclosed comments) must be int your LONG SCRIPT HEADER, which unfortunately you didn't post :)

Comment: Hmm. There may be more that you've not said here. These seem like straightforward scripts - so I'm wondering *why* you're using cmdexec (vs a job step that just runs SQL) and what command you're actually executing?

Comment: Hi Damien,cheers but the rest of the script is vast - as I say above this is the section where the error is referenced and no further comments occur in the script.

Comment: Yes, but if you're using cmdexec, you're not (presumably) just passing it the name of an .sql file - you're presumably firing off some kind of command - osql? sqlcmd? Something else? It might be pertinent to list what command line is being used to execute this SQL.

Comment: I see, sorry I'd misunderstood what you wanted to see. OSQL command rather than script. I'll add to the original question

Comment: In the 2000 version of OSQL, `ED` used to be a command, and under certain circumstances, the system ignores leading spaces before commands - so try making sure that line 4's first non-space characters aren't `ED` and see if that cures it (also, consider switching the SQLCMD, since OSQL may not be supported in the future)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Damien - "ED" was the issue. Got rid of that and the issue disappeared. Much appreciated - and I can't see I'd ever have figured that out myself. If you post as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: We'll also look at leaving OSQL behind. It's been S.O.P. to call scripts this way since I started here and we rely on the detail of its logging, but I'm sure there's a better approach. Once we've made the move I'll do some research into this and suggest to my manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2000 version of OSQL, `ED` used to be a command, and under certain circumstances, the system ignores leading spaces before commands - so try making sure that line 4's first non-space characters aren't `ED` and see if that cures it

For both [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), the documentation says:

> The `!!` and `ED` commands are no longer supported by osql.

However, it's possible that the commands are still *recognised*, even if they're not processed, and the difference in behaviour is purely one of whether a command is recognised when it has leading spaces in front of it. Apparently, this is so in 2008 but not on 2005.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered similar problem in SQL 2012. I had GO statement before end comment */.
Removing the GO statement within the comment before */ resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is your problem lies in `pr_printdate` procedure/function.

You might want to check and/or post the content of that one too ;)

Comment: @DanBennett: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, but I think not the issue. I hadn't posted before because as you can see, nothing in there that could throw this error and we run the sp elsewhere without this problem

Comment: cheers marc_s will do. Wonder if the bold emphasis was neccessary though given that Im not in preschool and you didn't just catch me poking another kid in the eye .

Comment: Ah well, the procedure indeed seems basic enough.  

When executing your `osql` command directly from the command line, do you get the same results?

Comment: thanks for your help Julien - see above, the issue was with presence of ED in a comment in the script